# Flexbox: Single Column to Stacked Multi-Column

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I encounter this layout issue a lot:

Small screens - items are stacked in a single row, usually an image followed by some text, then a smaller sub-area for extra miscellaneous:

[image: one column]

Medium screens and up - items are reshuffled to 2 columns, image and misc stuff on the left, text on the right:

[image: two columns]

I feel like I should be able to do this with flexbox, but I can't figure out how. I get that I can arrange the items in columns using:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
    width: 50%;
}
.one {
    order: 1;
}
.two {
    order: 3;
}
.three {
    order: 2;
}
```

But the problem is there doesn't seem to be a way to break the items into 2 columns without setting a fixed height, which obviously doesn't work too well for responsive.

Is there a way to force the columns to break at certain points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. By making width 100% at mobile size. they take up their own line.

```
.container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    width: 50%;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}
.box3 {
    background-color: purple;
    float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .box2 {
        float: left;
    }

    .box1,.box2,.box3 {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dfgs3tLr/4/)

Comment: Sorry If you checked a second ago... look now.